# Pytorch Cuda Runtime Error (with Properly installed Drivers)

Tags: gpu, pytorch, nvidia

When I run

```
import torch
torch.cuda.FloatTensor([1.])
```

I seem to be getting the error: `RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (38) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:50`.

I'm using Debian (Stretch). Checking the nvidia driveron the console:

```
/sbin/modinfo nvidia_current
```

returns:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.9.0-11-amd64/updates/dkms/nvidia-current.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        418.74
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
srcversion:     AB4044DE27C9CA55579A110
```

when I do `nvcc --version`, I get:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jun_12_23:07:04_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.2, V9.2.148
```

On python, when I do

```
import torch
print(torch.version.cuda)  
print(torch.cuda.device_count())
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

I get:

```
9.2.148
0
False
```

I've tried doing `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0`, but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you solve it ?